# Error in Exception handler when not connected to database in Laravel

Tags: php, pdo, exception, laravel-4

I have the following code in my `app/start/global.php` file:

```
App::error(function(\PDOException $exception)
{
     return Response::view('errors.db',array(),503);
});
```

If I shutdown my DB and run it on my login page it I get the correct response. However once logged in, If I shutdown the DB, I get the following error on page refresh:

```
Error in exception handler: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

The above is presented on a white page. Only if I comment the code I get the laravel stack trace:

```
PDOException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I also tried tried putting it my `filters.php` file to no avail:

```
App::before(function($request, $response)
{

    App::error(function(\PDOException $e, $code)
    {
        Log::error( 'FATAL DATABASE ERROR: ' . $code . ' = ' . $e->getMessage() );

        return Response::view('error.down',array(),503);

    }); // end of App::error

});
```

Comment: Is mysql server running? Check server config to find where is it storing the `mysql.sock` file. Use that path in php.ini

Comment: Hi, this is a deliberate test to check how the app reacts if mysql goes down. It is not giving me the expected redirect/response.

Comment: @aspiringCodeArtisan did you solve this problem? If so, how?